# Should general tags be added when there is a more specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I am referring to this question [Image of a disconnected set is disconnected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823888/image-of-a-disconnected-set-is-disconnected). It is tagged as "real-analysis", "metric-spaces" and "connectedness".

My question is, should it be tagged as "general-topology" as well? I realized "connectedness" is a subtopic of topology, and thus a more specific tag. Since I'm unsure of it, I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Here is a similar older question: [Tagging: Choose the most tags that fit, or choose the most narrow tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9741) I think that it is good for a equation to have one of the broad tags (it is more likely to get noticed, large tags have more followers). And also a specific tags - that is useful when somebody uses tags for searching. Of course, sometimes we run into the problem with only five spots for tags. I'll add that in the linked case, I'd consider the tag (examples-counterexamples), too.

Comment: Not knowing head or tail of topology you can give little value to this comment,but in general  say the inequality tag I think it is good to add a more general tag say -'algebra precalculus' which would give some additional *context* on the question that you are mostly looking for algeraic method for proving the inequality

Comment: That's a pretty old Question, almost five years since posting.  Perhaps if you were led to find that Question out of a personal interest, it would motivate a tag-only edit to make it easier for others to find.   If it were a recent Question then replacing real-analysis with general topology as the general tag would make sense.  Martin's suggestion of examples-counterexamples is also appealing, given the nature of the request.

Answer (score 10):

I think sometimes, yes, particularly when a more specific tag is context dependent on a broader, more general field.

For example, the tag  might be used for a question in geometry, or perhaps in a question in group theory (i.e. symmetric groups), or in a discrete math class when the question might concern symmetric relations.

The tag  might concern a a question in the field of geometry or analytical geometry, or a question in algebra-precalculus, or in calculus, in reference to trigonometric substitution in integrals.

When tagging a  question, whether  or  can make a big difference in terms of the level of answer to provide.

There are many such sub-topics with tags that are relevant in different, broader fields, and in such cases, including a broader tag can help clarify the context in which a question is being asked.

Another consideration is that many answerers select tags in which they are interested.  I, e.g., tend to select more general tags.  So a question with only the tag "cyclic groups" may fall under my radar, although I've selected both abstract algebra and group theory as tags of interest.  So when the tags chosen are very narrow in scope, there may be many answerers who haven't listed all the 100 or so tags under the umbrella of a general subject as tags of interest.

Basically, I'd advice every asker to include at least one general tag, for the last reason I cite for doing so.

Comment: +1, particularly for the last sentence.

Comment: +1 there. I also have a limited list of my favorite tags and all of them are reasonably general.